# Change default CSS styling of `shinydashboardPlus::descriptionBlock()`

Tags: css, r, shiny

I find `shinydashboardPlus::descriptionBlock()` quite nice but I am a bit frustrated not being able to change its styling within R. How can we achieve that?

- `header` is necessarly **bold**,
- `text` is necessarly in UPPERCASE,
- Using `HTML()` in `number` put the icon to the next line.

Show case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      box(
        solidHeader = FALSE,
        title = "Status summary",
        background = NULL,
        width = 4,
        status = "danger",
        footer = fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            descriptionBlock(
              number = "17%", 
              numberColor = "green", 
              numberIcon = "caret-up",
              header = "not bold please", 
              text = "set me in lowercase please", 
              rightBorder = TRUE,
              marginBottom = FALSE
            )
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            descriptionBlock(
              number = HTML("<h4>icon?</h4>"), 
              numberColor = "red", 
              numberIcon = "skull-crossbones",
              header = "using html put", 
              text = "icon to next line", 
              rightBorder = FALSE,
              marginBottom = FALSE
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Description Blocks"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with `shinyDashboardPlus`, but this article should apply to customizing CSS regardless of the package: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problems you need to insert css statements that equally specific as the css code supplied by the package.

- To sole the bold header insert `.description-block>.description-header { font-weight: 500; }`
- to remove the always Uppercase insert `.description-block>.description-text { text-transform: none; }`
- With the Icon problem. The problem is that you are using a `<h4>` tag. And this is by default a block element which moves the next object to a new line. Here you can either use a different tag such as `<span>` or set the display attribute to `inline-block`. In the example below I used the later solution

All together it would look like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(
HTML("
.description-block>.description-text {
    text-transform: none;
  }
.description-block>.description-header {
    font-weight: 500;
}
.description-percentage>h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
")
        )
      ),
      box(
        solidHeader = FALSE,
        title = "Status summary",
        background = NULL,
        width = 4,
        status = "danger",
        footer = fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            descriptionBlock(
              number = "17%", 
              numberColor = "green", 
              numberIcon = "caret-up",
              header = "not bold please", 
              text = "set me in lowercase please", 
              rightBorder = TRUE,
              marginBottom = FALSE
            )
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            descriptionBlock(
              number = HTML("<h4>icon?</h4>"), 
              numberColor = "red", 
              numberIcon = "skull-crossbones",
              header = "using html put", 
              text = "icon to next line", 
              rightBorder = FALSE,
              marginBottom = FALSE
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Description Blocks"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. Regarding the icon, the issue is that as soon as the argument stores any `HTML()` the icon goes to the next line, which is something we want to prevent.

Comment: @yeahman269 ok I added what I think is the solution to your problem with the Icon.

Comment: Top answer! Thanks.