# Color dynamic box() based on the value which comes from a widget inside the dynamic box() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the `shiny` app below I color the box based on the value of the `sliderInput()` which included inside the `box()`. The issue is that the box does not initially displayed if it does not have a value.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      
                      #mybox2Red{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: red; border-left-style: solid;}
                      #mybox2Green{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: green; border-left-style: solid;}
                      "))
      ),
    
    uiOutput("box2")
      )
      )


server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  
  output$box2<-renderUI({
    req(input$vr)
    if(input$vr<=5){
      tags$style(
        type = 'text/css',
        "#mybox2Red{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: red; border-left-style: solid;}"
      )
      box(
        id="mybox2Red",
        title = "title", 
        closable = TRUE, 
        width = 10,
        status = "danger", 
        solidHeader = F, 
        collapsible = TRUE,
        collapsed = T,
        sliderInput("vr","Set value range",min = 0,max=10,value =  5)
      )
    }
    else{
      tags$style(
        type = 'text/css',
        "#mybox2Green{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: green; border-left-style: solid;}"
      )
      box(
        id="mybox2Green",
        title = "title", 
        closable = TRUE, 
        width = 10,
        status = "danger", 
        solidHeader = F, 
        collapsible = TRUE,
        collapsed = T,
        sliderInput("vr","Set value range",min = 0,max=10,value =  5)
        
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you relay the value over a reactive value that can easily be done. Now you can initialize `ValueRange` outside of `renderUI` and you circumvent the issue this way.

I changed the `renderUI` a bit. Using the `if` the way you did requires maintaining the dame code twice. Unless you intend to add more differences to the 2 box states it will be a lot easier in the future (and easier to read). Now the condition changes only the box id. But - of course - you can ignore that if it does not make sense for what you have in mind.

Please note, that each update of the slider will collapse the box because of `collapsed = T`.

```r
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      #mybox2Red{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: red; border-left-style: solid;}
      #mybox2Green{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: green; border-left-style: solid;}
      "))
    ),
    uiOutput("box2")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  ValueRange <- reactiveVal(5)
  
  observeEvent(input$vr, ValueRange(input$vr))
  
  output$box2 <- renderUI({
    req(ValueRange)

    box(
        id=ifelse(input$vr<=5, "mybox2Red", "mybox2Green"),
        title = "title", 
        closable = TRUE, 
        width = 10,
        status = "danger", 
        solidHeader = F, 
        collapsible = TRUE,
        collapsed = T,
        sliderInput("vr","Set value range", min = 0, max=10, value =  ValueRange())
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I gave you the answer since it covers the original Q but its a little more complicated finally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022707/pass-reactiveval-as-values-in-sliderinput-in-a-shiny-app