# Pass reactiveVal() as values in sliderInput() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I color the dynamic `box()` based on the number of rows of a dynamic dataset (`valurange`).I just use the `iris` dataset as an example here.

When the number of rows of the dataset is less than 5 the color of the box will be red, otherwise it will be green.The issue is that I cannot use my `reactiveVal()` as values in the `shiny` widget that sets the number of rows in my dynamic dataset.

I get `Error in : In sliderInput():` min`,` max`, and` value `cannot be NULL, NA, or empty.`

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      #mybox2Red{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: red; border-left-style: solid;}
                      #mybox2Green{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: green; border-left-style: solid;}
                      "))
      ),
    uiOutput("box2")
      )
      )


server <- function(input, output) {
  Value1 <- reactiveVal(5)
  Value2 <- reactiveVal(10)
  
  observeEvent(input$vr, Value1(input$vr))
  observeEvent(input$vr, Value2(input$vr))
  
  valuerange<-reactive({
    iris<-iris[Value1():Value2(),]
    
  })
  
  
  output$box2 <- renderUI({
    req(Value1)
    req(Value2)
    box(
      id=ifelse(nrow(valuerange())<=5, "mybox2Red", "mybox2Green"),
      title = "title", 
      closable = TRUE, 
      width = 10,
      status = "danger", 
      solidHeader = F, 
      collapsible = TRUE,
      collapsed = T,
      sliderInput("vr","Set value range", min = 0, max=10, value =  c(Value1(),Value2()))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I do not understand. Please update the question to elaborate it a bit.

Comment: check now. in this case there is a slider range instead of a slider to set the number of rows of the dataframe that determines the color of the box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Shiny input slider range values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181744/r-shiny-input-slider-range-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting Value1 and Value2 to the same vector from the slider and not separating the lower and upper values. I think you meant

```
  observeEvent(input$vr, Value1(input$vr[1]))
  observeEvent(input$vr, Value2(input$vr[2]))
```

Comment: that is based on your answer above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261038/how-to-put-a-reactive-value-inside-a-reactiveval-in-a-shiny-app